# What are the possible way to cache static assets from different domains?

Tags: javascript

How can i cache javascript static files on [www.foo.ru](http://www.foo.ru) from [www.abc.ru](http://www.abc.ru) ?

I try load it by script tag (set src attribute), but when i go to [www.abc.ru](http://www.abc.ru) requests is sending again, cache is ignored. Does browser separate cache by origin or something else?

Comment: Can you please provide a code snippet to better understand your issue?

Comment: Cross-domain caching has been disabled in major browsers for awhile now as it could be abused for cross-site user tracking: https://www.stefanjudis.com/notes/say-goodbye-to-resource-caching-across-sites-and-domains/. Long story short, you can't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Terry said in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75361513/what-are-the-possible-way-to-cache-static-assets-from-different-domains#comment132976396_75361513), you can't do that directly. It used to be possible, but it was an information leak (`http://malicious-site-example.com` could see that it gets a really fast response to `http://example.com/some-asset` and use that information [probably in combination with other similar heuristics] to infer that you've been on `http://example.com` lately). So now, the cached response is only used for the origin that originally requested it — that is, effectively different origins have different caches.

Presumably you only want to do this on a pair of sites where you control both of them. In that case, you might use an `iframe` on `foo.ru`'s page that directly loads a page from `abc.ru` that does the load. Then it's `abc.ru` that's doing the request, and it's cached such that it's connected to `abc.ru`, not `foo.ru`. You can hide the `iframe` by making it zero-height or off the page or similar.